# Cut out polygons from a large raster

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp

I'm trying to cut out polygons from a large raster using gdalwrap by mask .kml.
When I don't set the resolution of the output file everything works great.

```
gdalwarp -dstnodata -9999 -q -cutline kml_file.kml -crop_to_cutline -dstalpha -tr 10.0 10.0 -of GTiff geotiff_file.tif output_file.tif
```

But when I try to set the resolution of the output file, the polygon geometry changes

```
gdalwarp -dstnodata -9999 -q -cutline kml_file.kml -crop_to_cutline -dstalpha -ts 900.0 900.0 -of GTiff geotiff_file.tif output_file.tif
```

How can I get a raster with a resolution of 900x900?

Comment: I see that you set the resolution in the first command `-tr 10.0 10.0` but in the latter example you set the image size `-ts 900.0 900.0`. Perhaps `-tr 900.0 900.0` is what you want?

Comment: @user30184, I'm sorry, I mixed up the terms. I need to get a 900x900 raster without changing resolution in target georeferenced units.

Comment: So you want to get a rectangle of size 9x9 km? How does it match with your cutline? Is your cutline a rectangle of that size?

Comment: @user30184, no, I want to get a 900x900 pixel raster with a polygon in the center

Comment: GDAL tools does not offer a functionality to expand your cutline into some fixed size rectangle. You must do that outside GDAL. Either you generate a properly sized rectangular polygon and use that as a cutline, or find the  corners of such polygon. Then you can use `-te` with gdalwarp or `-projwin`with gdal_translate.

Comment: @user30184, Thanks to. So you have to go on a more difficult path in the final part of the work.

Comment: Well, with some scripting it can be made automatic - find the centroid of the polygon, generate 450 m buffer, take the envelope of this buffer circle, and there is your cutline for a 900x900 box. Hopefully the polygon fits inside this box. Actually it does not need to happen outside GDAL. GDAL can do all this but gdalwarp doesn't.

Comment: @user20184, The fact of the matter is that I do not need meters, but pixels. The area of the polygon can reach 300 hectares. Just after processing, the rasters will be fed into the SSD neural network. I can use resize, but then the georeference will be lost.

Comment: Then you do want to use target size `-ts` as you did, but the problem is that cutline is accurate. If the polygon is  100 units high and 200 units wide then the pixel size of the 900x900 pixel output  is ((100/900),(200/900)). You must then take the bigger of height or width of the polygon and grow the smaller extent to same value. With this modified geometry you can ask for a 900x900 pixel output.

Comment: @user30184, thank you. I will try this solution.